# Swap the ng-repeat element in angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I want to set seven after six how could i fixed it into view without changing $scope.myJson.

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    {{ctrlTest}}<hr/>Ng-Repeat<hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="json in myJson">
        <li>{{json}}</li>
    </div>
</div>

angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.ctrlTest = "Applying";
    $scope.myJson = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "eight", "nine", "seven"]
    $scope.jsons = function(){
        console.log('callback called');
    }
})
```

Please see fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/757/

Comment: not sur you will be able to do this... the rendering is supposed to be based on your model, so if you don't want to change your model...

Comment: Change position from this json  $scope.myJson

Comment: don't change `myJson`, change its copy: `$scope.JsonCopy = angular.copy($scope.myJson);` and append "seven" to the copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following is the only solution I came up with by creating an custom filter and custom `compareFunction`

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ctrlTest = "Applying";
  $scope.myJson = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "eight", "nine", "seven"]
  $scope.jsons = function() {
    console.log('callback called');
  }
}).filter('customsort', function() {
  return function(list) {
    var sortOrder = {
     'one': 1,
     'two': 2,
     'three': 3,
     'four': 4,
     'five': 5,
     'six': 6,
     'seven': 7,
     'eight': 8,
     'nine': 9
    }
    list.sort(function(a, b) {
      return sortOrder[a] - sortOrder[b];
    })
    return list;
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
  {{ctrlTest}}
  <hr/>Ng-Repeat
  <hr/>
  <div ng-repeat="json in myJson | customsort">
    <li>{{json}}</li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for response please see this fiddle does not work for me http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/762/

Comment: Can you please take a look at the snippet. I have created a filter which you didn't.

Comment: I agree see my json response change

Comment: Ok as per new `JSON` response, here is updated fiddler. http://jsfiddle.net/scorpy2007/HgDA7/765/

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want to change the original array you can provide a custom orderBy function

```
<div ng-repeat="json in myJson | orderBy: customSortOrder">
    <li>{{json}}</li>
</div>
```

depending on your use case the custom sort order functino can look something like this

```
const stringToNumber = {
        one: 1,
    two: 2,
    three: 3,
    four: 4,
    five: 5,
    six: 6,
    seven: 7,
    eight: 8,
    nine: 9
}
$scope.customSortOrder = function(item) {
        return stringToNumber[item];
}
```

I updated your jsfiddle for a full example http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/759/

Answer (score 0):

One way that you could do this is with a filter or orderBy on the ng-repeat

Here is an example

```
angular.module('app',['QuickList']).controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    $scope.ctrlTest = "Applying";
    $scope.myJson = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "eight", "nine", "seven"]
    $scope.jsons = function(){
        console.log('callback called');
    }

    $scope.sortFunction = function(obj){
        var correctOrder = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"];
        return correctOrder.indexOf(obj);
    }
})
```

Here is the view

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller='mainCtrl'>
    {{ctrlTest}}<hr/>Ng-Repeat<hr/>
    <div ng-repeat="json in myJson | orderBy:sortFunction">
        <li>{{json}}</li>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HgDA7/760/